# Is this wiki sentence problematic?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

In wiki's page of *[Orthonormal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis#:%7E:text=Using%20Zorn%27s%20lemma%20and%20the%20Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt%20process%20(or%20more%20simply%20well%2Dordering%20and%20transfinite%20recursion)%2C%20one%20can%20show%20that%20every%20Hilbert%20space%20admits%20an%20orthonormal%20basis)*, there's such a sentence.

> Using Zorn's lemma and the Gram–Schmidt process (or more simply well-ordering and transfinite recursion), one can show that every Hilbert space admits an orthonormal basis.

Seems that it's problematic. If the space is not separable- no countable orthonormal basis is admitted, then the basis could be uncountable, how can you apply the Gram–Schmidt process?

Comment: You can apply Gram-Schmidt by transfinite recursion on an uncountable set the same way you apply it by ordinary recursion on a countable set.

Comment: @EricWofsey If you are at step $\alpha$ which is a limit ordinal, you need to subtract an infinite series (actually an $\alpha$-sequence) from a vector, how do you know that's always viable?

Comment: @EricWofsey Ok, I get it now. Only at most countably many inner products of a vector with another from an orthonormal set could be nonzero.